# How to Inject new element in SlateJS Editor DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

**How to inject new react component/element into SlateJS Editor DOM?**

I want to inject a new element within the SlateJS editor's DOM, not above or below.

Most of SlateJS's examples would transform nodes, but it doesn't allow for direct injecting into the SlateJS DOM. That is within the editor context.

EG

```
SlateJS Typing
INJECTED REACT COMPONENT
SlateJS Typing
SlateJS Typing

<div slatejs editor> 
  <div child div>
  // Want to insert a react component here
  <div child div>
</div>
```

Right now, you can add a new react component above or under the SlateJS editor, but not within.

```
    <Slate
        editor={editor}
        value={value}
        onChange={value => setValue(value)}>
        // <Tags /> Added component on top of SlateJS Editor
        <Editable
            placeholder="Enter some rich text…"
            spellCheck
            autoFocus
            onKeyDown={event => {
                switch (event.key) {
                    case '/': {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        console.log('/ Command')

                        // How to DOM inject into the current SlateJS component? 
                        ReactDOM.render(<Tags />, ...)
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
        // <Tags /> Added component UNDER SlateJS Editor
    </Slate>,
```

My current solution is trying to inject via ReactDOM, but I'm having trouble getting the actual SlateJS component, since I can't set the ID, making document.query difficult.

How could I inject a new react component within the SlateJS dom?

Comment: Have you thought about rendering multiple Editable components, each representing a tag e.g. H1, then you could add your component as a block?

I've not used Slate.js before but am looking at different editor options for my app and will also look to implement a slash command feature that could open a drop down menu.

Comment: That MAY be possible, but you'll be in for a world of hurt. The slatejs site has a rich text example. I think the proper way to do it is to create a custom node then set it as void. A maintainer said on github that plate used that method to create image components that couldn't be edited. 

Very confusing though, I didn't understand it.

Comment: Yeah when I asked they said it'd break it, in the end went with titap and got it working with that, tbh I think it's a similar concept to slate where you add a custom node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I injected the React component into the H1 div in Elements. Although, this method is buggy.

That is, keep everything the same in the Rich Text example except the elements, modified below.

[Rich Text Example Line](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/richtext.tsx#L133)

```
const Element = ({ attributes, children, element }) => {
  const style = { textAlign: element.align }
  switch (element.type) {
    case 'heading-one':
      return (
        <h1 style={style} {...attributes}>
          {children}
          // Just inserted the react component in the h1 div
          // Easiest way, but causes a bunch of slate errors when trying
          // to click the react component line
          <REACT_COMPONENT />
        </h1>
      )
    default:
      return (
        <p style={style} {...attributes}>
          {children}
        </p>
      )
  }
}
```